# In how many different ways to select unordered 5 elements from a set with three elements when repetition is allowed?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

In how many different ways to select unordered 5 elements from a set with three elements when repetition is allowed?

---

I know that total ways are $C(n + r - 1, n - 1)$.

But, I am mainly interested in how five elements are selected from $3$ elements.
Take an example of set of 3 elements as $\{A,B,C\}$ ?

I am thinking like this. Is this correct ?

ABACC
CAABB
CCABB
ABBBB................

Comment: you said "in order", "repetition allowed". So, one way is AABAC, another is ACABC

Comment: If order matters, shouldn't the answer simply be $3^5?$ Am I missing something crucial here?

Comment: @Mirko, Is this correct ? ABACC CAABB CCABB ABBBB................

Comment: you changed "in order" to "unordered". So, ABABC is the same as AABBC, and same as BBACA. They all say 2 A's, 2 B's, and 1 C. You could try listing all possibilities: 5A; 4A1B; 4A1C; 3A2B; 3A1B1C; 3A2C; 2A3B; etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such "selections" are called multisets. Given a set $X$ a *multiset* on $X$ is a function $f:\>X\to{\mathbb N}_{\geq0}$. For an $x\in X$ the function value $f(x)$ indicates how many times the element $x$ "occurs" in the multiset under consideration. The sum $\sum_{x\in X} f(x)\leq\infty$ then is the *cardinality* of this multiset.

Your example is about multisets on $X:=\{A,B,C\}$ of cardinality $5$.